# Particle Anti-Particle annihilation in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, antimatter

What special distinction does the interaction of a particle with its anti particle have compared to an interaction with some other particle?

People often say when a particle and an anti-particle interact, they annihilate. Today I was watching a public talk on Interstellar Travel (not important here) and anti-matter propulsion was also discussed. What does annihilation mean?

I studied a little bit of Quantum Field Theory, quite a fair amount of time ago, so I don't know if I am saying this right but here goes. I am thinking of some significance of a transition from $\bar{\varphi}(x,t)\varphi(x,t) |0> $ sort of states to  $\varphi^{\dagger} (x,t)\bar{\varphi}^{\dagger}(x,t) \gamma(x,t, \vec{-p}) \gamma(x,t, \vec{p}) \bar{\varphi}(x,t)\varphi(x,t) |0> $ sort of states, where $\varphi$ is some field. I don't know if terms like these in the propagator correspond to any sensible Lagrangian. What is special about such transitions (modulo my mistakes, with corrected terms given by a good Lagrangian)? Is it that the amplitude of photon production is the dominant one, when you expand a good propagator?

Comment: What does annihilation mean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation